# How to use BLE of a vehicle to control audio and call controls?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm working on a project where in I need to use BLE of a vehicle and through the vehicle's buttons I want to accept/reject calls as well as control my music running on my phone. How can I execute this? I would pointers on this as I'm a newbie to the electronics world.

Just been through primary materials on BLE.

Comment: I'm certain what you're describing is impossible (the systems you're talking about don't use BLE; they use HFP and a mix of other profiles), but it's also unclear what you're describing. Which "vehicle's buttons?" Many (if not most) modern vehicles already have buttons to do these things (just not with BLE), so it's not clear what you're trying to implement. Do you mean you want to add physical buttons that have these functions to a car that doesn't have them?

Comment: Yes, the vehicle has a board with an embedded BLE. We want to use this to implement music and call controls using this BLE which will connect to the phone's bluetooth.

Comment: What do you mean by "a board with embedded BLE?" Do they document how it bridges to their audio and call system? If they do not document this, it almost certainly doesn't do so. BLE is not a normal way to interact with those systems, and would have to be done in a completely custom way that only the manufacturer could document for you.